Adafruit Feather M4 CAN Express overvoltage protection
I would like to read CAN signals from my car over the OBD-II connector.
My question is, whether I need to implement any kind of (overvoltage) protection, so the Adafruit won't get harmed (and vica versa), or I can connect the CAN signal lines directly to the Adafruit?
Thank you very much for your answers in advance!

How do you intend to supply your external board? USB?

I can take it from the OBD-II connector itself, though I would need a DC-DC converter circuit.
Another convenient way would be just powering it from my laptop or a power bank via USB, though I'm a bit worried that some current can be back-fed into the car....

In that case maybe add reverse polarity protection and definitely TVS on the supply.

Solder a TVS into the USB cable? Don't want to incorporate +1 PCB.
Sorry, I'm rather a SW than a HW engineer.

That was under the assumption that you'd take supply from the OBD connector. Either way it's not nice to "hot plug" powered boards together and the OBD connectors don't seem designed to be used in that way(?). As in ensuring GND pins touch first.

So powering it from the laptop / power bank shall be okay, and getting only the CAN lines from OBD, right?

It doesn't really matter except car supplies are notoriously noisy with spikes and surges. You'll have no current limit either way. The CAN lines are likely rugged enough to survive hot plugging - if in doubt add (bidirectional) TVS there as well.

The MCU board has a CAN physical interface. It should be generally safe to connect to another device with a CAN bus, if done properly.
The TCAN1051HGV is a fault-protected CAN transceiver. However as the exact part number in the BOM is not known, it's likely not the automotive grade version of the chip.
Now, if you fry up the MCU board, it's cheap enough you can always buy a new one. The same unfortunately may not apply to your car.

Thank you! So I can fry the car with this Adafruit board?

@Zsolt Unless you do ridiculously clumsy things like shorting CAN GND with 12V etc there's no reason to believe you will be harming anything.
